# Define serverless framework Api Gateway response schema similar to request schema

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, api-gateway

I am trying to update to [serverless.com](https://serverless.com) v2

There is a section in the doc that describes how to set the request json schema on [#request-schema-validators](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#request-schema-validators)

```
functions:
  create:
    handler: posts.create
    events:
      - http:
          path: posts/create
          method: post
          request:
            schemas:
              application/json:
                schema: ${file(create_request.json)}
                name: PostCreateModel
                description: 'Validation model for Creating Posts'
```

I am curious if there is a similar feature for responses, to define the schema for different statuses.

I was using [serverless-aws-documentation](https://github.com/deliveryhero/serverless-aws-documentation) but I see that it is no longer maintained for serverless v2.

Any suggestions for replacing serverless-aws-documentation?